# Using a SystemVerilog interface as an input port to a module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

There are multiple modules where I take as input (among other things) a

```sv
input[15:0] instruction
```

Then, in all these modules I copy and paste the following code:

```sv
wire aluBit = instruction[15];
wire jumpBit = instruction[14];
wire[2:0] mainOpcode = instruction[13:11];
wire constantBit = instruction[10];
wire standaloneBit = instruction[9];
wire[7:0] embeddedConstant = instruction[9:3];
wire[2:0] instrParam1 = instruction[8:6];
wire[2:0] instrParam2 = instruction[5:3];
wire[2:0] instrDestination = instruction[2:0];
```

I believe interfaces would streamline this and get rid of the copy-pasting. But I don't understand how to make it work.

Note: If it helps, I am using a SystemVerilog to Verilog converter called sv2v.

I tried alot, for example:

```sv
interface Instruction;
    logic[15:0] instruction,
    logic aluBit, jumpBit, isConstantInstruction, standaloneBit,
    logic[2:0] mainOpcode, instrParam1, instrParam2, instrDestination,
    logic[7:0] embeddedConstant

    always_comb aluBit = instruction[15];
    always_comb jumpBit = instruction[14];
    always_comb mainOpcode = instruction[13:11];
    always_comb isConstantInstruction = instruction[10];
    always_comb standaloneBit = instruction[9];
    always_comb embeddedConstant = instruction[9:3];
    always_comb instrParam1 = instruction[8:6];
    always_comb instrParam2 = instruction[5:3];
    always_comb instrDestination = instruction[2:0];
endinterface
```

Then I tried to define the ControlUnit module, with an Instruction input port:

```vs
module ControlUnit(Instruction instruction);
    wire example = instruction.jumpBit;
    ...
endmodule
```

It just does not compile though.

Comment: what does it mean: *It just does not run though.*?

Comment: It does not get properly converted into normal Verilog. The interface I wrote as an example does not really matter though, as I don't know what I'm doing. I am asking for the right syntax to write an interface in this context. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of an `interface` definition (using the OP as a baseline) and its use as a `module port` taking the `interface` to be a bundle of wires with no ports (meaning the interface itself has no ports).

The posted code is missing semicolons on the wires near the beginning.

- Added semicolons to interface
- Declared the `interface` (must be defined outside a `module`, a `module` and an `interface` are both fundamental design units)
- Created `module` ControlUnit with `interface` port , and printed a couple of the `interface` values.
- Instantiated somemodule in a testbench
- Declared an interface type variable to connect to the module port
- Drove the interface variable with a constant
- Connected interface variable to the testbench DUT
- Ran the testbench

interface:

```
interface Instruction ();
    logic[15:0] instruction;
    logic aluBit, jumpBit, isConstantInstruction, standaloneBit;
    logic[2:0] mainOpcode, instrParam1, instrParam2, instrDestination;
    logic[7:0] embeddedConstant;

    always_comb aluBit = instruction[15];
    always_comb jumpBit = instruction[14];
    always_comb mainOpcode = instruction[13:11];
    always_comb isConstantInstruction = instruction[10];
    always_comb standaloneBit = instruction[9];
    always_comb embeddedConstant = instruction[9:3];
    always_comb instrParam1 = instruction[8:6];
    always_comb instrParam2 = instruction[5:3];
    always_comb instrDestination = instruction[2:0];
endinterface
```

module:

```
module ControlUnit(
  Instruction instruction
  );
  
    wire example = instruction.jumpBit;
  
  initial begin
    #1;
    $display("instruction.jumpBit = %0b",instruction.jumpBit);
    $display("instruction.aluBit = %0b",instruction.aluBit);
  end
  
endmodule
```

testbench:

```
module tb ();
  
  Instruction tb_stub();
  
  assign tb_stub.instruction = 16'ha5a5;
  
  ControlUnit dut(
   .instruction(tb_stub)
  );

endmodule
```

produces:

```
instruction.jumpBit = 0
instruction.aluBit = 1
```

on Cadence, Mentor, Synopsys, and Aldec simulators.

Comment: Hm, I was trying to do something like: 
```module somemodule (Instruction instruction_inst);```

But that did not work. What you did though, passing the instruction word and instantiating the interface inside the module does work.

Comment: When I try that I get:
```sv2v: could not resolve modport binding instruction for port instruction of type Instruction, within scope tb```

Could be an error with sv2v rather than a syntactical one.

Comment: Recommend reporting to the vendor or author of the sv2v tool that you have an interface port example that works on four different commercial sv simulators but fails on sv2v.